# Determine the mode of the gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Tags: gamma-distribution

How do you determine the mode of a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ? Without looking on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: you want to maximize $x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x}$ over $x \in (0,\infty)$.

The derivative is $e^{-\beta x}[(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2} - \beta x^{\alpha-1}] = x^{\alpha-2} e^{-\beta x} (\alpha-1-\beta x)$, which is zero when $x= \frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}$ or $x=0$.

- If $\alpha \ge 1$, direct inspection shows that $x=0$ is not the mode, since the pdf is zero there. Thus the other critical point $\frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}$ must be the mode.
- If $\alpha < 1$ the pdf has a positive asymptote at $x=0$. Moreover the derivative is strictly negative for all $x>0$, so it decreases from $\infty$ to $0$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

Thanks to JeanMarie for the clarifications.

Comment: How do we know it is zero when $x=\frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}$ or $x=0$. Zero is not the mode because $x>0$ correct?

Comment: Look at the curve : It is not 0 because in 0, the pdf is 0 !

Comment: @JeanMarie can you please explain more

Comment: You are looking for a mode: it is necessarily a values of $x$ such that the pdf f(x) has a $>0$ value. In $0$ it has a zero value at least for the cases $\alpha>1$ (for the other cases, one cannat speak about a mode because the pdf has a vertical asymptote.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the clarifications!